# MongoDB order of operators

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I am trying to find movies which:

- Contains only "Comedy" and "Crime" in their "genres".
- "Comedy" is listed first

I know I could query as such:

```
.find({ "genres": ["Comedy", "Crime"] })
```

However, I cannot grasp why the following doesn't work:

```
.find({ 
  "genres.0": "Comedy",
  "genres": { $size: 2 },
  "genres": { $all: ["Comedy", "Crime"] }
}
```

As a result, I get entries such as:

```
["Comedy", "Crime", "Drama"]
```

But why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `genres` twice in your find-object, which means the second entry overwrites the first. When you have two conditions for the same field, you either need to use the $and operator or combine them like this: `"genres": { $size:2, $all: ["Comedy", "Crime"] }`